Redirecting Microsoft Edge download folder to Onedrive
I am trying to redirect my default download director of Microsoft Edge to my Onedrive/Documents.
I have right now C:\Users${user_name}\OneDrive – Companyname\Documents
Unfortunately its not working correctly. It downloads the file on a location in Onedrive which does not sync so you can't see the file online.

You can try to open the Edge browser menu, then find "Downloads" in the left navigation bar, then click change at "Location", navigate to your OneDrive folder in the pop-up file explorer and select the corresponding folder. Please note that you can only select "Folder" here, not files.
